# Найти координаты центра рандомного многоугольника

Tags: javascript, svg

На вход подается рандомный многоугольник (из SVG файла).
С помощью одной библиотеки извлек координаты многоугольника (черными точками указаны на рисунке)

К примеру, вот:

[image: многоугольник]

Необходимо найти "относительный" центр фигуры.

С помощью этих формул попытался:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

, но получилось так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, может есть другие способы нахождения центра фигуры.

Не суть на каком языке реализация будет, лишь бы работало корректно.

Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: Получилось правильно. Что значит "или"? У фигуры два центра что ли? Объясните, что для Вас означают слова "относительный центр фигуры".

Comment: То есть нужно найти точку, которая будет принадлежать многоугольнику ( не суть важно, где именно), главное, чтобы точка принадлежала многоугольнику.

Comment: Вы шутите? Таких точек бесконечное множество.

Comment: Вот тут нагляднее https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIMqG.png

Comment: Понятно, не можете объяснить: -1.

Comment: Нужно найти центр тяжести. Может так понятнее...

Comment: Так, заходим на второй круг. Вы уже нашли центр тяжести. Чем он Вас не устраивает?

Comment: Найденная точка не принадлежит многоугольнику.

Comment: С центрами тяжести это бывает. От этого они не перестают быть центрами тяжести.

Comment: Программа "Раскраска" (фотография по номерам) решает такую проблему. Жаль доступа к исходному коду к ней нет.

Comment: Я скорее всего не так вопрос поставил, просто, я не знаю, как такую точку назвать. Значит центр тяжести это не то определение, которое мне нужно. Но все-равно спасибо. Буду искать дальше...

Comment: Если я правильно понял задачу, вам скорее нужен центр вписанной окружности максимального радиуса. Только как его искать я не знаю